# Convert date and hours/minutes/seconds to correct format javascript

Tags: javascript

I got date in format '20190702' and hours/minutes/seconds in format '125657'
What is the easiest way to convert it to  `07/02/2019, 12:56:57`

```
const time = "125657";
  const chuncks = str.match(/.{1,2}/g).join(":"); //12:56:57
```

What about date?

Comment: What if hours/minutes/seconds is '138' ? would what be 01:03:08? Where is that input coming from?

Comment: yes correctly, from back end. It comes like this one `130039`. so variant with 138 not possible

Comment: I personally would pretend a better format from the backend, like an ISO string or something similar. Date and time standards are there from a while ago, there aren't really many significant reasons to reinvent the wheel. The format you're using may lead to undesired results.

Comment: Fix your backend to get date in the format you need. Don't fix it on the frontend.

Comment: Yes , I aggree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *easiest* is maybe this:

```js
const time = "125657".replace(/(..?)(..)(..)/, "$1:$2:$3");
const date = "20190702".replace(/(....)(..)(..)/, "$2/$3/$1");

console.log(date, time);
```

The question mark in the first pattern could serve if the time string could have 5 digits instead of 6. If you are certain you always get 6 digits, you can leave it out.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `substr` function to extract a part of string and then combine the parts to form new string

```js
const time = "125657";
const date = "20190702";
const formattedTime = `${time.substr(0,2)}:${time.substr(2,2)}:${time.substr(4,2)}`
const formattedDate = `${date.substr(4,2)}/${date.substr(6,2)}/${date.substr(0,4)}`
console.log(`${formattedDate}, ${formattedTime}`)
```

Comment: Fails with `const time = "95657"`.

Comment: In comments, OP says it will come always in 6 digits always.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) to parse dates, it will accept most formats.

```js
let momentDate = new moment.utc('20190702', 'YYYYMMDD');
console.log("Parsed date: ", momentDate);

let momentDateTime = new moment.utc('20190702125657', 'YYYYMMDDHHmmss');
console.log("Parsed date (with time): ", momentDateTime );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)
You provide pattern along with data.

Here, "hh" means "hours" in pattern.

```
"use strict";
const moment = require("moment");

console.log(moment("125652", "hhmmss").toDate());
```

Comment: moment is not required to convert this as the format is known and fixed always

Comment: Yes, but it is much easier to do it with moment, is not it?

Comment: but its not worth to include a whole library just to convert this.

Comment: It depends on project and it's limits. I am generally against reinventing wheel, especially for server-side code and single-page apps with cache. But for heavy-loaded website additional library may be not so good idea.

Comment: look at my answer, I've converted it without any library, because the format is fixed

Answer (score 1):

Assuming fixed length input strings of decimal digits, you could do something like this:

```js
const date = "20190702";
const time = "125657";
const formatted_date = date.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, "$3/$2/$1");
//const formatted_time = time.match(/\d{2}/g).join(":");
const formatted_time = time.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, "$1:$2:$3");
const formatted_date_time = `${formatted_date}, ${formatted_time}`;
console.log(formatted_date_time);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the year was 2-digit, you could have used the same exact logic and just add a `reverse`, but since it's a different length, I advise you a manual composition:

```js
const date = '20190702';

const chunks = date.match(/.{1,2}/g);

const formattedDate = [chunks[3], chunks[2], chunks[0]+chunks[1]].join('/');

console.log(formattedDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) library to format your date. In your case, the code may look like:

```
var time = '20190702,125657';
var formated_time = moment(time, "YYYYMMDD,HHmmss").format('DD/MM/YYYY,HH:mm:ss');
```